# How does node.js and jwt authorization work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am building an MEAN(MongoDB,Express.js, Angular 5, Node.js) stack app.I am using jsonwebtoken node_module. How does the authenticaion work? The backend sends the token, and when the the user wants to access some route(like router.get('/users') ) he passes the token to the http header. Then what should the backend do?
Does it only compare the secret. If yes, doesn't that mean that a user can access and change the data of another user?

Comment: This is well documented in the JWT spec as well as in the various libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the backend should verify that the token is valid. When you create the JWT token, you'll want to insert some kind of ID in order to differentiate users.

When the backend receives the token, it simply needs to read the ID in order to know which user is authenticated.

I suggest looking into how JWT token works.